# Redefine 'pause' behaviour in c++ console app in windows

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, io

I have a windows c++ console app and I want to redefine behaviour of program when I pressing 'pause' key durning runtime. How I can do this?  
If there is no way to redefine behaviour key 'pause', how can I detect pressing any specific key asynchronously?  
I know about WM_KEYPRESSED message, but as I understand it works only for window UI apps.
Maybe there some solutions in boost?

Comment: use a while loop...

    `a = std::cin >> ("press space to continue"); while( a != ' '){a = std::cin << ("press space to continue");}`

Comment: @angel The question is about the key labelled PAUSE on the keyboard

Comment: ooopss... sorry, I misunderstood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetWindowsHookEx` to install a low-level keyboard hook, `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`, that traps and discards the offending key press.

Comment: Yep it seems that is solution.
But there is a little funny problem.
I found this example http://ideone.com/JCGSAT and start to experiment with it.
But when i changes
"while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { }"
to
"while (true) {}"
my keyboard and mouse stopped working and computer starts beeping when i pressed to mouse buttons.
It is very strange behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: Can you hep me with this problem?

Comment: OK. You need another thread for this. You need a message queue for the window hook. But you can't run the message queue out of the main thread of a console app. So, create a new thread on startup. Set the hook there, in the thread. And then run your message loop in that thread. An alternative is to run a separate background process. A gui app with no visible window that hijacks PAUSE.